# Convert to Vec<i32> to i32

Tags: parsing, rust, vec

I was trying to create a function that trasform a Vec to i32

```rs
fn vec_to_int(digits: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        let n = &digits.iter().fold(0, |acc, digit| acc * 10 + digit);
        println!("Vec:{:?} to: {}",digits,n);
        *n
    }
```

the results of this function was just as expected

```
Vec:[3, 4, 2] to: 342
Vec:[4, 6, 5] to: 465
Vec:[9] to: 9
Vec:[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9] to: 9999999
```

but when i try using the vec`[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1]` the result was

```
Vec:[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1] to: 1410065399
```

why this happen and what i can do to improve the code?

I know that i could just parse the Vec to a string than parse to a number but i want to know why it happen and why exactly `1410065399`

Comment: The maximum value of a `i32` is `2147483647`, which is less than `9999999991`

Comment: This is why you test in debug mode instead of release mode. In debug mode, overflow checks are on and so this will panic: "attempt to multiply with overflow"

Comment: I feel obligated to complain that you are storing the digits in the wrong order. The digit for 10^0 has to be at index 0, the digit for 10^1 at index 1 and so on. It probably doesn't matter for your use case, but people getting this wrong brought us the travesty that is big endian. (To be fair, the error probably happened when Europe adapted Arabic numerals without adjusting the writing direction from right-to-left to left-to-right many centuries ago, but it definitely happened again when people built big-endian computers.)